# A theorem about the dimension of affine subspaces

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

The related theorem and its proof is:[image]

My problem is that from $E\cap{F}\not=\emptyset $, how it is deduced that $E$ and $F$ are reduced to their associated vector subspaces? Also, what is the relationship between $<E,F>$, i.e, the smallest affine subspace that contains $E$ and $F$, and $E'+F'$?

Answer (score 0):

The following Lemma  provides the necessary tools, the rest is linear algebra.

[image: ][1]]

[image]

[image]

[image]